# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'can': Invalid argument (In 5.10.102.1 WSL2)

Tags: sockets, config, wsl-2, socketcan

I'm setting up the socket can because I want to test it, but the same message comes out as the title.
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'can': Invalid argument`
and `dmesg` display like blow.

```
[ 1297.682601] can: disagrees about version of symbol dev_queue_xmit
[ 1297.682603] can: Unknown symbol dev_queue_xmit (err -22)
[ 1297.682605] can: disagrees about version of symbol consume_skb
[ 1297.682606] can: Unknown symbol consume_skb (err -22)
[ 1297.682609] can: disagrees about version of symbol dev_add_pack
[ 1297.682610] can: Unknown symbol dev_add_pack (err -22)
[ 1297.682623] can: disagrees about version of symbol register_pernet_subsys
[ 1297.682624] can: Unknown symbol register_pernet_subsys (err -22)
[ 1297.682627] can: disagrees about version of symbol proto_unregister
[ 1297.682628] can: Unknown symbol proto_unregister (err -22)
[ 1297.682630] can: disagrees about version of symbol kfree_skb
[ 1297.682631] can: Unknown symbol kfree_skb (err -22)
[ 1297.682633] can: disagrees about version of symbol sock_register
[ 1297.682634] can: Unknown symbol sock_register (err -22)
[ 1297.682638] can: disagrees about version of symbol proto_register
[ 1297.682639] can: Unknown symbol proto_register (err -22)
[ 1297.682644] can: disagrees about version of symbol dev_remove_pack
[ 1297.682645] can: Unknown symbol dev_remove_pack (err -22)
[ 1297.682646] can: disagrees about version of symbol sk_free
[ 1297.682647] can: Unknown symbol sk_free (err -22)
[ 1297.682652] can: disagrees about version of symbol sk_alloc
[ 1297.682653] can: Unknown symbol sk_alloc (err -22)
[ 1297.682655] can: disagrees about version of symbol unregister_pernet_subsys
[ 1297.682656] can: Unknown symbol unregister_pernet_subsys (err -22)
[ 1297.682658] can: disagrees about version of symbol netif_rx_ni
[ 1297.682659] can: Unknown symbol netif_rx_ni (err -22)
[ 1297.682660] can: disagrees about version of symbol sock_efree
[ 1297.682661] can: Unknown symbol sock_efree (err -22)
[ 1297.682662] can: disagrees about version of symbol skb_queue_purge
[ 1297.682663] can: Unknown symbol skb_queue_purge (err -22)
[ 1297.682674] can: disagrees about version of symbol proc_create_net_single
[ 1297.682675] can: Unknown symbol proc_create_net_single (err -22)
[ 1297.682676] can: disagrees about version of symbol skb_clone
[ 1297.682677] can: Unknown symbol skb_clone (err -22)
[ 1297.682684] can: disagrees about version of symbol sock_init_data
[ 1297.682685] can: Unknown symbol sock_init_data (err -22)
```

I don't know how fix it. please help me.

I used blow codes to setting socketCan in WSL2 version 5.10.102.1

```
cd ~ // in linux directory
wget https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/archive/refs/tags/linux-msft-wsl-5.10.102.1.tar.gz
tar -xf linux-msft-wsl-5.xx.xx.x.tar.gz # tar -xf linux-msft-wsl-5.10.102.1.tar.gz
cd WSL2-Linux-Kernel-linux-msft-wsl-5.xx.xx.x/ # cd WSL2-Linux-Kernel-linux-msft-wsl-5.10.102.1/
cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > .config
```

blow codes maybe the order is wrong, but I tried it twice so all module files installed

```
make prepare modules_prepare -j $(expr $(nproc) - 1)
gedit ./Microsoft/config-wsl // gedit is editting program
```

In wsl-config copy and pasted blow code.

```
# config-wsl
CONFIG_CC_CAN_LINK=y
CONFIG_CC_CAN_LINK_STATIC=y

# CONFIG_HAMRADIO is not set
CONFIG_CAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_RAW=m
CONFIG_CAN_BCM=m
CONFIG_CAN_GW=m
CONFIG_CAN_J1939=m
CONFIG_CAN_ISOTP=m

# CAN Device Drivers
CONFIG_CAN_VCAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_VXCAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_SLCAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_DEV=m
CONFIG_CAN_CALC_BITTIMING=y
CONFIG_CAN_KVASER_PCIEFD=m
CONFIG_CAN_C_CAN=m
# CONFIG_CAN_C_CAN_PLATFORM is not set
    # CONFIG_CAN_C_CAN_PCI is not set
CONFIG_CAN_CC770=m
# CONFIG_CAN_CC770_ISA is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_CC770_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_CAN_IFI_CANFD=m
CONFIG_CAN_M_CAN=m
# CONFIG_CAN_M_CAN_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_M_CAN_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCIEFD=m
CONFIG_CAN_SJA1000=m
# CONFIG_CAN_EMS_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_EMS_PCMCIA is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_F81601 is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_KVASER_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCMCIA is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_PLX_PCI is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_SJA1000_ISA is not set
# CONFIG_CAN_SJA1000_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_CAN_SOFTING=m
CONFIG_CAN_SOFTING_CS=m

# CAN USB interfaces
CONFIG_CAN_8DEV_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_EMS_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_ESD_USB2=m
CONFIG_CAN_ETAS_ES58X=m
CONFIG_CAN_GS_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_KVASER_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_MCBA_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_UCAN=m
# end of CAN USB interfaces

CONFIG_CAN_DEBUG_DEVICES=y
# end of CAN Device Drivers
```

```
make modules -j $(expr $(nproc) - 1)
make modules_install 
cp arch/x86/boot/bzImage /mnt/c/Users/<username>/
sudo modprobe can
```

and then error message come out....

Comment: I fixed it... there is a problem with my ubuntu version...
default wsl2 Ubuntu version is 20.xx , and I install new version, 22.xx then... it works